# How to redirect from an Azure sub-domain name?

Tags: azure

I have some HTML widgets hosted on an Azure website. I would like to move these to a different Azure website.

Unfortunately, the mobile apps that consume these widgets are referencing their Azure sub-domain name directly. Example: `old_widgets_site.cloudapp.net`

Now I would like to shut down the old location where the widgets are hosted and move over to a new Azure website. Example: `new_widgets_site.cloudapp.net` :)

Is there a way for me to shut down the old website while still supporting the older mobile apps? Or do I have to keep the old app alive so I can host some kind of URL redirect mechanism on it?

PS - I know it's much better to reference a "virtual" domain name and have that redirect to Azure using DNS CNAMEs and I will. My question is not about that, but about redirecting *.cloudapp.net sub-domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding there is no option within Azure Web Sites to configure a redirect from within the portal.

What you could do is keep the old Web Site active and replace the content with a URL redirect statement in the web.config file (See: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module). Of course that does mean you need to keep the old Web Site active.

Maybe you want to submit this idea using the Azure Feedback Forums: http://feedback.azure.com/

Comment: Thanks. I followed your advice and submitted this as an idea to the Azure UserVoice: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/6054178-allow-redirecting-from-an-old-website-to-a-new-one . Would appreciate your support in voting :)